# Which shape is the worst to pack in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, spheres, packing-problem

Yesterday I bought a box of chocolates and remarked with a friend how they had just put enough in to get above a certain transparent window to the inside but everything else was empty space. I added that this was probably particularly bad because it doesn't seem like the spherical-shaped chocolates would pack very well (in comparison to, say, cubes).

I wondered if in fact the sphere is the worst "shape" to pack, but I'm not entirely sure what the most natural formalisation of this question is. The following is my first attempt, which I have no idea how to prove, but I am open to suggestion for better formalisations:

We will call a *tile* of $\mathbb{R}^n$ a convex compact subset and we will say two tiles are *almost disjoint* if their intersection is a subset of their boundaries. I can't necessarily remember what little measure theory I knew but probably we want some kind of normalisation condition and I *think* convex compact subsets are measurable, so let's say we also want tiles to have (Lebesgue) measure one.

**Is it true that the tile with least packing density for any $n$ is the $n$-dimensional closed ball (of appropriate size to have volume 1)?**

If we remove the convexity condition but say, we still want our tiles to be connected, my thoughts are that there is in fact *no* tile of least packing density as we can just take $n$-dimensional (closed) annuli which are thinner and thinner with increasing radii to retain having volume 1 and these have arbtrarily low packing density. **Is this correct also?**

EDIT: Based on a suggestion in the comments, I wish to clarify that "packing" here permits tiling by translation and rotation of the tiles.

Comment: To be clear, it may be that there is a simple argument which shows that with any tiling by "tiles" as I defined them you always make it worse by converting the tiles into spheres, but given how difficult it has been to get results concerning sphere packing I wasn't sure if these questions were instead really difficult.

Comment: Can't comment on your actual question, but I can confirm that compact subsets are closed, and therefore measurable.

Comment: I was given a box of truffles like that. This one, however, had two layers. Except that the second layer was corrugated packing material only, and in fact there was only the one layer.

Comment: (i) The second surmise is correct and annular shells are a good example: Without convexity there is no positive lower bound on packing density. (ii) It may be worth specifying whether or not tiles must be packed as translated copies (in which case triangles in the plane have density $0.5$), or it rotations are permitted (triangles tessellate).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang thank you for your first comment and for your second, I have clarified that rotations are permitted.

Comment: For $n\ge2$ the tile $\Vert x\Vert_p\le f(n,\,p)$, with $f$ defined to impose your chosen normalization, achieves perfect packing if $p\in\{1,\,\infty\}$ and imperfect packing for $p\in(1,\,\infty)$, all of which make the tile convex. That the packing is worst when $p=2$, which is already not obvious (but feels morally true given how special the $p=2$ norm is), is a corollary of your convex tiles conjecture; and it wouldn't surprise me if a proof of this can be tweaked into a more general result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://phys.org/news/2015-03-geometry-least-packable.html) article says that as of 2015, it was conjectured but not known to be true for $n=3$, and is known to be false for $n=2$.

Comment: Very nice to hear about this!